# Nesting GSP tags in Grails

Tags: grails, gsp

This no worky, the onClick handler is removed by Grails when I do a view-source on the HTML output (Grails 1.2.1) What am i missing?

I'm trying to internationalize the confirmation message displayed in the javascript

```
  <g:actionSubmit id="deleteButton" value="Delete" action="deleteActivities" onclick="return confirm(' ${g.message(code="common.confirm.delete", args="['Activity']") } ');"/>
```

Comment: It may not be the problem, but you ought to use `g.message(...).encodeAsJavaScript()` when you're inside a JavaScript string literal.

Comment: I don't think you can use any of the Grails goodness with JS, unless you use a plugin ( [jawr plugin](http://mrhaki.blogspot.mx/2011/11/grails-goodness-internationalize.html), for example ).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it as follows:

```
<g:actionSubmit id="deleteButton" value="Delete" action="deleteActivities" onclick="return confirm(' ${message(code: "common.confirm.delete", args: ['Activity'])} ');"/>
```

Comment: @Ian and Sergei, thanks for the suggestions, still no luck.     <g:actionSubmit id="deleteButton" value="Delete" action="deleteActivities" disabled="true" class="button cancel" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete?');"/>
    %{-- No worky
      <g:actionSubmit id="deleteButton" value="Delete" action="deleteActivities" disabled="true" class="button cancel" onclick="return confirm(' ${message(code: "common.confirm.delete", args: ['Activity']).encodeAsJavaScript() } ');"/>
--}%
[/code]